# Suggested synonym/retag: rename "starships" to be a synonym of "spaceship"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

We have 2 questions tagged [starships](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starships). We also have 16 tagged [spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceship).

It seems that there's very little point to have a specific tag for "starships" - The only meaningful distinction would be if the former explicitly applied to inter-star travel and the latter to space travel within one system as contrast, but that isn't supported by either exact English connotations, nor the set of 16 questions for spaceship.

I proposed to change [starships](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starships) to be a synonym of [spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceship).

While at it, [starship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starship) should also be changed thusly, but it doesn't yet exist and you can't propose a synonym based on non-existing tag.

If you agree, and have >=5 upvotes in [spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceship), please feel free to up-vote the synonym suggestion here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/spaceship/synonyms

If approved, I will take care of minor re-tagging if it will be necessary.

Comment: You don't need to make a separate meta post for each synonym when there's little controversy! Just say: “any objections to synonymizing [tag:foo] → [tag:bar] and [tag:wibble] → [tag:wobble]?”

Comment: @Gilles - sorry for spam :(   This is the way I thought the process should be based on reading the rules on synonym creation page (e.g. "Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4"). My assumption was that META post was the correct way to inform the people that they have a new tag synonym to approve/reject. If that's incorrect, please post a little blurb as an answer as far as proper procedure.

Comment: That's the proper procedure for controversial cases. It's not needed for clear-cut cases. What I usually do (here or on other sites) is to get a couple of regulars' opinion in chat, then if everyone agrees (have a mod) set up the synonym, otherwise ask on meta.

Comment: Also, you should have changed the title from `Suggested synonym/retag: rename “sorcery” to “magic”`

Answer (score 3):

Given the support here and in the tag synonym votes, I went ahead and "made it so".

Comment: +1 for Picard reference :)  and thanks!